# how to set fuse bit code for 16mhz oscillator

Tags: avr

Currently I am trying to figure out what the correct fuse settings for my ATmega16 are. I want to use an external crystal oscillator with a frequency 16 MHz.On what point I must focus on much? I didnt got much knowledge from the articles.
It is said working on fuse bit is difficult, there is a chance of damaging IC.

Answer (score 0):

To change to external oscillator you should write 0xEE in Low fuse, you could check clock system clock section in atmega16 datasheet or [read this description](http://treehouseprojects.ca/fusebits/)

edit lfuse using avrdude

```
sudo avrdude -c usbtiny -p m16 -U lfuse:w:0xEE:m
```

Remove usbtiny and specify your programmes

> It is said working on fuse bit is difficult, there is a chance of damaging IC.

Of course there is a chance to damage the IC, but there is no learn without try!

Comment: i see using 0xEE much. what if i use 0xEE? what is the difference? and what about high fuse? oXc9?

Comment: yes you are right, i misread it with the externl clock, also note that atmega16 may not work at 16MHz, i think 8MHz is the maximum. try and tell me does it work with 16MHz or not